# On a TP-Link router, what's the difference between Storage Sharing, FTP Server, and Media Server?

Tags: router, ftp, local-storage, media-server

Can someone properly explain? As I can understand in all three cases you just connect a USB hard drive to the router.

I'm using a TP-Link TL-WDR4300 router.

[image: tp-link usb setup menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media server would be for sharing media over your local network to an Xbox, Laptop, or HTPC.

FTP server is so that you can access the storage drives from outwith your network, from your office for example.

Storage sharing, I imagine, would be to allow several people on your network to access the same storage drives to backup files.